# Adding sine and cosine

Tags: wave-equation

I need to convert $b\cos(ax)+c\sin(ax)$ into something like $d\cos(ax-y)$. I thought I could use the identity $\cos(x-y)=\cos(x)\cos(y)+\sin(x)\sin(y)$, however that's without considering my constants b and c.

Comment: Perhaps consider what $\sqrt{b^2+c^2}$ represents

Comment: [My answer to this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1076500/transforming-linear-combination-of-the-cosine-and-sine-function/1076507#1076507) can help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the method of subsidiary angle.

Let $$b = d\cos\phi,$$ $$c=d\sin\phi.$$ In other words, $$d=\sqrt{b^2+c^2},$$ $$\phi=\tan^{-1}\frac{c}{b}.$$ Then $$b\cos(ax)+c\sin(ax)=d\cos\phi\cos(ax)+d\sin\phi\sin(ax)=d\cos(ax-\phi).$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\sqrt{b^2+c^2}\left( \cos \phi \cdot \cos (ax)+\sin \phi \cdot \sin (ax) \right)$$
$$\sqrt{b^2+c^2}\cdot \cos \left( \phi -ax \right)$$
where $\phi=\arccos \dfrac{b}{\sqrt{b^2+c^2}}$