# How do we calculate $\int\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\cos(x) - 3\sin(x)}$?

Tags: trigonometry, indefinite-integrals

\begin{align*}
\int\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\cos(x) - 3\sin(x)}
\end{align*}

I can't pick this numbers for formula $\cos(x)\cos(y) - \sin(x)\sin(y)$.

May you help me? Maybe I can use different way, but this way is more simple

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find $ \int \frac{1}{2\sin(x)-3\cos(x)}dx$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1581568/find-int-frac12-sinx-3-cosxdx)

Comment: You can combine the two trigonometric functions [like so](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sqrt%281+%2B+e%5E2%29+sin%28x+%2B+tan%5E%28-1%29%281%2Fe%29%29%3Dcos%28x%29%2Be+sin%28x%29).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that:

$$\int \frac{dx}{\cos(x)-3\sin(x)}=\int\frac{dx}{-\sqrt{1+(-3)^3}\sin\left(x+\cot^{-1}(-3)\right)}=-10^{-\frac12}\int \csc\big(x-\cot^{-1}(3)\big)dx$$

Since $\frac d{dx}\ln\left(\tan\left(\frac {x+a}2\right)\right)=\csc(x+a)$:

$$\int \frac{dx}{\cos(x)-3\sin(x)}=c-10^{-\frac12} \ln\left(\tan\left(\frac {x-\cot^{-1}(3)}2\right)\right) $$

Please correct me and give me feedback!

[Differentiated result](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=ddx+-1%2Fsqrt%2810%29+ln%28tan%28%28x-acot%283%29%29%2F2%29%29)

Answer (score 1):

To choose numbers as you want, you need that the sum of their squares is $1$.  You can achieve this by writing
$$
\frac1{\cos x-3\sin x}=\frac1{\sqrt{10}}\,\frac1{\frac1{\sqrt{10}}\,\cos x -\frac3{\sqrt{10}}\,\sin x}.
$$

Comment: The coefficients don't match.

Comment: Indeed, my bad. It shoul be good now.