# Prove that $a\sin x+b\cos x=\sqrt{a^2+b^2} \sin\left(x+\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)\right)$

Tags: trigonometry

Recently, I came across a beautiful question. I tried several ways of solving it, but I could not reach anywhere. The question goes like:

Prove that:

$$a\sin x+b\cos x=\sqrt{a^2+b^2} \sin\left(x+\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)\right)$$

Please give me a hint. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Divide and multiply LHS by $\sqrt(a^2+b^2)$ , and recall the formulae for sine and cos . (opposite/hyp , etc. ) . Then see if you can use any sum formula...

Comment: Consider $C\sin(x+\theta)=a\sin x+b\cos x$, then expand the LHS using trig addition formulae, then compare coefficients. Are you sure you searched this correctly, it's very well known. [The first link on Google](https://www.myphysicslab.com/springs/trig-identity-en.html)

Comment: I marked this as a duplicate of a particular question (since I happen to remember that I posted [an answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/856600/409) to it), but there are other instances on Math.SE. See, for instance, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/948329/409) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1588325/409). I'm sure you can find at least a few more. Searching is a little tricky, but looking through the "Related" questions can be helpful.